# Matplotlib latex error when using logarithmic axis scale, version-dependent

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I get a latex error in matplotlib when running the following commands within python 2.7.15. It occurs when using a logarithmic axis scale. Whether the error appears or not depends on the matplotlib version, I tested with 1.5.1 (error does not occur) and 2.2.3 (error occurs). The error also only occurs when the code is executed within a single block (like in a function). See below for the minimal example (execute in two separate python consoles!). What exactly causes the error and how can I avoid it, while using the new matplotlib and tex mode?

Common code for both cases:

```
import sys
default_sys_path = sys.path
import numpy as np

def reproduce_error(old_matplotlib, outname):
    if old_matplotlib == True:
        sys.path = ['/opt/local/anaconda/anaconda-2.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages'] + default_sys_path
    else:
        sys.path = ['/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages'] + default_sys_path

    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    print matplotlib.__version__
    print matplotlib.__path__

    plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
    plt.semilogy(np.arange(1,10)*10**(-10))
    plt.savefig('/home/proxauf/%s' % outname)
    plt.close()
    plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False
```

Case 1 code and output (matplotlib 1.5.1):

```
reproduce_error(old_matplotlib=True, outname='test_mathdefault_old.pdf')

1.5.1
['/opt/local/anaconda/anaconda-2.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib']
```

Case 2 code and output (matplotlib 2.2.3):

```
reproduce_error(old_matplotlib=False, outname='test_mathdefault_new.pdf')

2.2.3
['/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 519, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 437, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1493, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2635, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1192, in draw
    renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1130, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 922, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 309, in _get_layout
    ismath=ismath)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 236, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 501, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 365, in make_dvi
    texfile], tex)
  File "/scratch/seismo/proxauf/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 344, in _run_checked_subprocess
    exc=exc.output.decode('utf-8')))
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
'$\\\\mathdefault{10^{-10}}$'
Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/proxauf/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/be547c40948f52354492209662050ad0.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (5058.9pt) is ignored.
Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (5058.9pt) is ignored.
) (./be547c40948f52354492209662050ad0.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mathdefault 

l.13 ...000000}{12.500000}{\sffamily $\mathdefault
                                                  {10^{-10}}$}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on be547c40948f52354492209662050ad0.log.
```

Comment: Have a look if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850541/2454357) helps you in any way.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It works fine for me on matplotlib 2.2.3, python 2.7.15.

Answer (score 2):

From that I understand the error is because of command `\mathdefault`. It is a command defined in the python, and no is a base command of Latex. Thus, to solve this problem, you need put above of `plt.semilogy(np.arange(1,10)*10**(-10))` the below commands:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\newcommand{\mathdefault}[1][]{}'
```

Thereby,the command \mathdefault will be defined and will do nothing.

I rewrote you code with those suggestions,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\newcommand{\mathdefault}[1][]{}'
plt.semilogy(np.arange(1,10)*10**(-10))
# plt.savefig('/home/proxauf/%s' % outname) ## outname????
plt.close()
rcParams['text.usetex'] = False
```